# In DBT BigQuery, how to both define & call macro from within the same file

Tags: google-bigquery, dbt

**trying_macro.sql**

```
{# {% macro get_four() %}
  2 + 2
{% endmacro %} #}

with
  t1 as (select {{ get_four() }} as four)

select * from t1
```

The docs - https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/jinja-macros - don't touch on whether it is possible to define and call a macro from the same file. When run in DBT, it throws an error:

[image]

We understand that we can save these in a separate `.sql` file in our `/macros` directory, but we have some macros that are very-clearly file specific, and we'd strongly prefer having the macros defined at the top of the file. Is this possible?

Comment: It's not working because you defined your macro inside a comment block. Remove `{#` and `#}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't something that's currently possible in dbt.  You can see some discussion on the possibility of supporting this in the future [on GitHub](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/discussions/5098).

Comment: As minor a feature as it seems on the surface, I understand from this thread why the implementation under the hood is not as simple. But damn it would be nice to have.